# Send a encrypted password form phone for authentication in Deivse rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise

I am developing a api in rails which is going to be consumed by mobile devices. Devise is my choice for authentication with auth_token enabled. My problem is I want to send hashed password from the mobile device for authentication. I don't know how Devise encrypts the password. I need a way to override the Devise encryption so that I could use mine both on the mobile devise and on the server side